# Correct pattern for php's date_format function

Tags: php, date-formatting

In PHP, what is the correct format pattern with date_format function to render date value '2014-06-18' as '18/jun'?
This is the code I tried but didn't work

```
<h3><?=date_format($evento->fecha,'j/M') ?></h3>
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you attempted? What have you researched?

Comment: @AzizSaleh, yes of course, i think the code is not needed but i have edited my question. That is just one of the pattern i used

Comment: @Kryten, in the link you provided dont see examples to resolve my case, nor here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kryten Not to be picky, but the format options are actually given in the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation.

Comment: @Kryten, that is another function, i will try with it. Please guys be patient i come from ASP.NET world i know very little of php.

Comment: @Elio.Batista What do you get when you run the code that you put in your question?

Comment: @PatrickQ, an empty string is what i get in my case. Database value comes as posted. Without formatting function it is rendering that same value with not problem.

Comment: If you have error reporting turned on (to include showing warnings) you should see this `Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface`

Comment: @PatrickQ fecha field is of type date in the database, it makes any diference with datetime datatype when using date_forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to employ both [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in something like this:

`echo date('d/M', strtotime('2014-06-18')) //outputs 18/Jun`

Comment: Since @Elio.Batista most likely has no need for an actual DateTime object (which is required by `date_format()`), this is probably the better way to go.

Comment: @PatrickQ, sorry i closed the question by mistake, thanks to funny people downvoting my question i no longer can open a new one.

Comment: i have this: 
<h3><?=date('d/M', $evento->fecha) ?></h3>
<h3><?=$evento->fecha ?></h3> and the results are '01/Jan' and '2014-04-29 00:00:00' respectively, as you see the format result do not correspond to the subjacent value

Comment: @Elio.Batista Look at how Timr does it in the answer. You have to use both `date()` and `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm

$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01

$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001

$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310

$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01

$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.

$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001

$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month

$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
```

Comment: Copying and pasting from a manual (and providing nothing else) is not an appropriate answer (to any question).

Comment: Sorry Patrick, thought I would leave the poster with some work to do! <h3><?=date_format($evento->fecha,'y/m/d') ?></h3>

Comment: Keep in mind, that the content on SO is licensed under the [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) as noted in the footer. A direct copy and paste of content without attribution may qualify as [plagarism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism?cb=1) under the Stack Exchange terms of use.

Comment: If you read the post correctly you will see the link goes to the manual, now you can get pedantic about it and say I should have named the link the PHP Manual, but as the post is about PHP, the question is tagged PHP, I would have thought it would have been implied